# Hardware keyboard keypress repeated in Safari HTML5 content

Tags: ios

I use Safari on iOS 12.4 on an iPad 6th Generation. When I use my hardware keyboard as input into an HTML5 game, it repeats until clicking on a button outside of the game. What can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: Is this in a web browser?  I assume the game is observing key down and key up.  The game isn't getting this information for an external keyboard

Comment: The game is observing WASD. This is in Safari.